# Detect Duplicate URL for domain names using javascript

Tags: javascript, url, dns

I want to code a check for duplicate url's, but a simple string match will not work, e.g. `string1 == string2`. Consider the following url's as an example:

1. www.facebook.com/authorProfile
2. facebook.com/authorProfile
3. http://www.facebook.com/authorProfile
4. http://facebook.com/authorProfile

Comment: Those are four different URLs. The first two are relative (so have to be resolved with a base URL). The last two might have the same content, or one might redirect to the other, or they might have different content. You can't safely assume the content will be identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function extract(str){
    var patterns = [
        "http://www.",
        "http://",
        "www."
    ];
    for(var i=0, len=patterns.length; i < len; i++){
        var pattern = patterns[i];
        if(str.indexOf(pattern) == 0)
            return str.substring(pattern.length);
    }
    return str;
}
```

This will convert all those links to `facebook.com/authorProfile` style so you can compare them.

```
links = [
    "www.facebook.com/authorProfile",
    "facebook.com/authorProfile",
    "http://www.facebook.com/authorProfile",
    "http://facebook.com/authorProfile"
];

for(var i=0, len=links.length; i<len; i++){
    console.log( extract(links[i]) );
}
// will produce 4 "facebook.com/authorProfile"
```

Comment: ohhhk thnx but I doubt it wud work for a URL in this pattern 
http:facebook.com ..I know 'http://' is the format but when typed in URL bar it does accept and resolve to www.facebook.com

Comment: @Zohaib Just append `"http:"` to `patterns` and it will handle this format

Comment: Oh yes Thanks. So to fully rely on this methos I need to check which all formats can arise so that I can handle those patterns in the pattern array.

Answer (score 0):

How about using javascript regex?  Basically, remove http:// and www.

```
.replace(/www.|http:\/\//g, '');
```

Example:

```
var s1 = 'www.facebook.com/authorProfile';
var s2 = 'facebook.com/authorProfile';
var s3 = 'http://www.facebook.com/authorProfile';
var s4 = 'http://facebook.com/authorProfile';

s1.replace(/www.|http:\/\//g, '');
s2.replace(/www.|http:\/\//g, '');
s3.replace(/www.|http:\/\//g, '');
s4.replace(/www.|http:\/\//g, '');
```

All become:

```
facebook.com/authorProfile
```